# Regex returning inexplicable results (to me)

Tags: mysql, regex, unicode, thai

I want to return entries from a table that match the format:

prefix + optional spaces + Thai digit

Testing using ยก as the prefix I use the following SQL

```
SELECT term
FROM entries
WHERE term REGEXP "^ยก[\s]*[๐-๙]+$"
```

This returns 9 entries, 4 of which don't have the correct prefix, and none of them ends in a digit.

```
ยกนะ
ยกบัตร
ยกมือ
ยกยอ
ยกยอด
ยกหยิบ
ยมทูต
ยมนา
ยมบาล
ยมล
```

It doesn't return

```
ยก ๑
ยก ๒
```

which I know are in the database and are the entries I want.

I'm very new to all this.  What am I doing wrong?

FWIW, this is against a MySQL database and everything is in Unicode.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried this in another language/environment?

Answer (score 0):

As quoted from the [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/regexp.html):

> The REGEXP and RLIKE operators work in byte-wise fashion, so they are not multi-byte safe and may produce unexpected results with multi-byte character sets. In addition, these operators compare characters by their byte values and accented characters may not compare as equal even if a given collation treats them as equal.

Doesn't seem like MySQL's `REGEXP` can handle the `[๐-๙]` range correctly due to the above.

Comment: That certainly is the problem then.  Thanks.

I find it amazing that in this day and age MySQL can't handle Unicode.

Answer (score 0):

I use utf8_general_ci and try.I matched

```
ยกนะ
```

with "^ยก[\s]*[๐-๙]+$" but did't matched ยก ๑.So I change the regexp to

```
"^ยก[ ]*[๐-๙]+$"
```

,and it can match

```
ยกนะ 
ยก ๑
```

Maybe the problem is character encoding.